# How to use categorical data neural network in tensorflow without estimator?

Tags: string, input, tensorflow

I am trying to build a neural network without using estimators. I have defined layers as,

```
x_categorical = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
x_numeric = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x_numeric,weights), biases)
l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x_categorical,weights), biases)
```

tf.matmul works well for numeric features but i also have some categorical features. So i am unable to use them 
I tried tf.string_to_hash_bucket_fast but it converts the string to int64 which is not supported by tf.matmul, i also tried tf.decode_raw. that also did not work. So please help me with this I want use categorical features as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle categorical values in a Neural Network you have to represent them in OneHot representation. If they are string (as it seems to be your case) you first have to convert them to "Integer representation". Step by step:

Using `from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder`

Define you categorial string values

`categorical_values = np.array([['Foo','bar','values'],['more','foo','bar'],['many','foo','bar']])`

Then encode them as integers:

```
categorical_values[:,0] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(categorical_values[:,0])
categorical_values[:,1] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(categorical_values[:,1])
categorical_values[:,2] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(categorical_values[:,2])
```

And use `OneHotEncoder` to obtain the OneHot representation:

`oneHot_values = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(categorical_values).toarray()`

Define your graph:

```
x_categorical = tf.placeholder(shape=[NUM_OBSERVATIONS,NUM_FEATURES],dtype=tf.float32)

weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([NUM_FEATURES,NUM_CLASSES]),dtype=tf.float32)
bias = tf.Variable([NUM_CLASSES],dtype=tf.float32)

l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x_categorical,weights),bias)
```

And execute it obtaining the results:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    _l2 = sess.run(l2,feed_dict={x_categorical : oneHot_values})
```

**Edit:** As requested, no-sklearn version.

Using just `numpy.unique()` and `tensorflow.one_hot()`

```
categorical_values = np.array(['Foo','bar','values']) #For one observation
lookup, labeledValues = np.unique(categorical_values, return_inverse=True)
oneHotValues = tf.one_hot(labeledValues,depth=NUM_FEATURES)
```

Full example on the JN linked below

Here you have a Jupyter Notebook with the code on my [Github](https://github.com/alberduris/stackoverflow/blob/master/categorical_data_neural_network_dilpreet/How%20to%20use%20categorical%20data%20neural%20network%20in%20tensorflow%20without%20estimator.ipynb)

Comment: Is similar function available in tensor flow ? i dont want to use sklearn.

Comment: @DilpreetSDhamija just updated the answer but, could I asked why you don't want to use sklearn but tensorflow yes? Just curious.